# /sbin/init does not exist - Bailing out, you are on your own. Good luck

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation

I'm trying to install arch linux. When I boot up, it gives me the message found below.

```
ERROR: Root device mounted successfully, but /sbin/init does not exist.
Bailing out, you are on your own now. Good luck.

sh: can't access tty: job control turned off
[rootfs /]# _
```

Comment: init should be located in /usr/bin/init and not /sbin/init

Comment: Did you use an old installation image and not `-Syu`?

Comment: I used the latest iso. Should I do a pacman -Syu before I install everything?

Comment: @Jeight `/sbin` and `/bin` are symlinks to `/usr/bin` on Arch Linux.

Comment: I used this install script because I'm not sure what I am doing. https://github.com/helmuthdu/aui

Comment: @strugee The question now is are the OP's Arch Linux /sbin and /bin using the sym links that it should have by default. That would cause the issue.

Comment: @Chance Can you please show the output of `ls -la /`

Comment: https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/attachment/u/0/?ui=2&ik=dc413709fc&view=att&th=141cf2fac866ff54&attid=0.1&disp=inline&realattid=1449300330465460224-local0&safe=1&zw&saduie=AG9B_P_4hLGozCTHdGwC5adKsrdx&sadet=1382160544040&sads=Ih7fo_tyyqoyk2oshn6udnj7dko&sadssc=1

Comment: @ChanceLeachman I really would recommend against using things like this. if you don't want to configure Arch the way the wiki recommends, or don't understand what you're doing, then Arch is probably not the right distribution for you (maybe try Mint or Debian). also, your link 404s. @Jeight FWIW, I suspect that he can just install the `systemd` package. maybe his script wasn't updated for the transition to systemd as init.

Comment: @Jeight Wrong-o. The traditional and correct place for `init` is in `/sbin`.  It certainly isn't anywhere in `usr`, because on systems where `/usr` is a separate partition, `init` is required first, because it is an init service that will mount the partition.  See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard#Directory_structure for an explanation of what `/sbin` is.

Comment: Output from my computer right now: `$ which init
/usr/bin/init`

Comment: @goldilocks That is where it is located. I didn't make the choice.

Comment: @goldilocks I'll explain better. On Arch Linux both /sbin and /bin are symbolic links to /usr/bin. That is where init resides. I know it's not the traditional method that many other distos use.

Answer (score 9):

You should need [systemd-sysvcompat](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/i686/systemd-sysvcompat/) if you want to use `init`. The `/sbin/init` is a simple symbolic link to `/lib/systemd/systemd` (see [PKGBUILD](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/systemd#n141)) provided by `systemd-sysvcompat`.

So if you want to boot your system you should add into `grub kernel line` (if you use grub):

```
init=/lib/systemd/systemd
```

If you don't want to use `systemd-sysvcompat` you should add the line above into your `GRUB's configuration`

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this problem and solved it by re-installing arch base system and **paying closer attention to the instructions** given. Specifically under [Syslinux - Installation on BIOS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/syslinux#Automatic_Install).

I chose to install ***syslinux*** and read the instructions too quickly and forgot to

> ***Configure syslinux.cfg to point to the right root partition.*** This step is **vital**.

My root partition which was on /dev/sda2 in my case, and as you can see below it is not pointing to it.

```
...
LABEL arch
    ...
    APPEND root=/dev/sda3 rw
    ...
```

It pointed to my home partition, /dev/sda3

Answer (score 2):

Download the very latest install ISO (2013.10.1 currently) from the [Arch Download page](https://www.archlinux.org/download/). Put that ISO on a CD or whatever and re-install.

Either you used an elderly installation ISO or something went wrong during your install. On my relatively up-to-date Arch server, `/sbin/init` is a symbolic link to `/lib/systemd/systemd`.

You could check that `/sbin/init` exists, and that either it's a real file or a symbolic link. If the latter, check to see if what the symbolic link says exists, is executable, is a file, etc etc. My guess is something in that process will show where the install went bad, but that you should probably re-do the install from a fresh download of the ISO image.

Comment: Arch does use `init`, in the sense that the kernel wants a program called `/sbin/init` (unless the bootloader passes a different value via the `init` option), and that the program with PID 1 is conventionally called `init`. It doesn't matter to the kernel whether this is the `init` from Systemd or from SysVinit or from Upstart or from BusyBox.

Answer (score 2):

I Know this post is old, but I have just encountered this problem, and I didn't find a good answer elsewhere, so here is my answer, hoping that this helps someone in the future.

In my case, when I was at the stage

```
ERROR: Root device mounted successfully, but /sbin/init does not exist.
Bailing out, you are on your own now. Good luck.

sh: can't access tty: job control turned off
[rootfs /]# _
```

There actually was a `/sbin/init`, which was nothing but a symbolic link to
`busybox`!

Here is what happened.
In Archlinux, the directory `/sbin` is a symbolic link to /usr/sbin.  And, as say other people, `/usr/sbin/init` symlinks to `/lib/systemd/systemd`.  But, in my case, I found out that the `/usr` directory was not mounted.

You basically need to mount the partition `/usr` as explained [on this ArchWiki page.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mkinitcpio#.2Fusr_as_a_separate_partitionarate_partition) You may also want to verify `/etc/fstab`, especially if you use one generated by `genfstab`.

Comment: A related answer is https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/392223/5132 and a related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247532/ .

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you used the wrong partition for root. Look up your loader entry (in /boot/loader/entries/arch.conf if you are using systemd-boot on Arch Linux like me), and ensure the 'root' UUID is your root partition.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue when installing Arch Linux with full-disk encryption, using systemd-boot.

I ended up missing 'base' when using pacstrap. I went back and added it with the archiso and it fixed my new install.

After adding 'base' with pacstrap, run `mkinitcpio -p linux` in arch-chroot.