# How to mount /usr at boot time without an initramfs?

Tags: systemd, initramfs

I'm having trouble booting into my system with systemd installed. I wouldn't like to use an initramfs, so I use a self-configured kernel which starts my kernel with the following in-built command line:

```
root=/dev/sda1 init=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd
```

But it will obviously not work, as the /usr is not yet mounted at this time. How can I make this work?

Comment: [systemd: Booting Without /usr is Broken](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/www/Software/systemd/separate-usr-is-broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple... don't separate `/` and `/usr` anymore. It's a pointless headache. If you have a partition for everything, `/` will be a nearly empty filesystem anyway. Merge them into one.

Example for merging `/` into `/usr`:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/root
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/usr
cp -a /mnt/root/usr /mnt/usr/usr
mv /mnt/usr/* /mnt/usr/usr/
cp -a /mnt/root/. /mnt/usr/.
```

Finally change the cmdline to `root=/dev/sda2`. Don't forget to adapt your `/etc/fstab` accordingly.