# Missing vmlinux file in /boot

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel, system-installation, hard-disk

This' my first Arch Linux install. I followed every installation step correctly but after rebooting my box I can't load up the Arch. I end up at a grub prompt. After hours of consulting Google I have realised that I am missing the **vmlinux** Linux kernel file in my /boot directory. Some people online claim they found the file in the root / folder and simply moved it to /boot folder to solve this.  However for me I am not able to trace the file in the / dir. How and where can I get the vmlinux file? I need it in order to boot my new Arch install. xo

Comment: What is the bootloader you are using? the file name should be `vmlinuz` not `vmlinux`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel image has to be in `/boot` if you followed all the steps correctly. What you can do is:

1. boot into the live cd.
2. mount the root partition somewhere.
3. `arch-chroot` into the root partition.
4. install the `linux` package. It would be wise to install `linux-lts` as well.

Don't forget to mount the `efì` partition before installing `linux`

Comment: It does not have to be in `/boot`. That is only a convention.  However many utilities are hardwired to assume it is in `/boot`, so best to follow the convention unless you known what you are doing.

Comment: I said the images have to be in `/boot` cos he said that he followed the installation manual. It's the default arch linux setup. Thanks for reminding though, the answer needs an edit.

Comment: Thanks guys I am now past this. However I got stuck here  https://ibb.co/hwCMJF .  Any ideas how I can commence? Google answers just confuse further since every thread is talking about something different. Please bear with my noob state. Thanks.

Comment: see this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96720/sbin-init-does-not-exist-bailing-out-you-are-on-your-own-good-luck/96781