# How does systemd handle unmounting /usr on shutdown, since it is mounted in the initramfs?

Tags: systemd

Systemd allows /usr to be mounted by the initramfs, similar to how the initramfs mounts the root filesystem.

But DefaultDependencies for mount units includes `Conflicts=umount.target`.  So systemd would try to unmount /usr, when it should not, e.g. `/usr/bin/systemd` will still running from that filesystem.

Doesn't this cause problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem is the documentation doesn't include this detail.  The code makes sure to handle this.

> /* Returns true for all units that are "magic" **and should be excluded from the usual start-up and shutdown
>                 dependencies.** We call them "extrinsic" here, as they are generally mounted outside of the systemd dependency
>                 logic. We shouldn't attempt to manage them ourselves but it's fine if the user operates on them with us. */

```
        if (!MANAGER_IS_SYSTEM(UNIT(m)->manager)) /* We only automatically manage mounts if we are in system mode */
                return true;

        if (PATH_IN_SET(m->where,  /* Don't bother with the OS data itself */
                        "/",
                        "/usr"))
                return true;

        if (PATH_STARTSWITH_SET(m->where,
                                "/run/initramfs",    /* This should stay around from before we boot until after we shutdown */
                                "/proc",             /* All of this is API VFS */
                                "/sys",              /* … dito … */
                                "/dev"))             /* … dito … */
return true;

        /* If this is an initrd mount, and we are not in the initrd, then leave this around forever, too. */
        p = get_mount_parameters(m);
        if (p && fstab_test_option(p->options, "x-initrd.mount\0") && !in_initrd())
                return true;

        return false;
}
```

Note it seems not to support cases where you *want* to unmount `/usr` in umount.target.  It is probably best to ignore systemd's claim that it itself supports mounting `/usr` without an initramfs.  This claim is made outside the git repo, and in the context of pointing out that many important projects have rejected support for systems configured this way.